# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Normally Everything is ok dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath works return a valid cell but rarely returns nil

I use Storyboard.And I cant catch exception Everythins is fine but My app in release sometimes gives this exception I can only see this exception in crashlytics

CategoryLeftTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryLeftTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Normaly above code is fine lots of time no problem but rarely it returns nil

Comment: We will need some code to help you. Can you add the code where you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath ?

Comment: post the related code to find out your problem

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, I can only guess. Thus, my guess is that you may be forgotten to give a name to the prototype cells of your table view. You can do it by clicking the cell and setting the cell identifier, it can be any name, but it will signify to programme that you are in interaction with that cell type.